# Cocoa - array not sorting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have this set

```
NSMutableSet *mySet = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: @"2", @"8", @"7", @"0", @"3", nil];
```

I copy the set to an array and sort it using

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[mySet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

The resulting array is in exactly the same order as the set and is not being sorted. Why?

thanks for any help.

EDIT: CORRECTING A TYPO.

Comment: copypasted your code - it sorts ok...

Comment: not in my code. Strangely, in my code, sortedArray has one object, instead of 5... it is like the array was being stored on a single entry of sortedArray... a kind of array inside an array... very strange...

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. It was an error while retrieving the original set. Now it is working fine. Thanks for all help you guys gave me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pasted and ran you code like this:

```
NSMutableSet *mySet = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: @"2", @"8", @"7", @"0", @"3", nil];
NSLog(@"mySet=%@",mySet);
NSArray *sortedArray = [[mySet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"sortedArray=%@",sortedArray);
```

Which outputs:

```
2010-03-17 11:06:27.982 iPhoneTestBed[41907:207] mySet={(
    0,
    2,
    7,
    8,
    3
)}
2010-03-17 11:06:27.984 iPhoneTestBed[41907:207] sortedArray=(
    0,
    2,
    3,
    7,
    8
)
```

I think your problem is with your logging of the sorted array. Perhaps you're accidentally logging the set instead of the array. I wasted half a day once doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, it correctly sorts, once I corrected the set construction to

```
NSMutableSet *mySet = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: @"2", @"8", @"7", @"0", @"3", nil];
```

Remember, `"abc"` is a `char*`, which is a primitive type which you rarely use in Objective-C, and you can't put it in `NSArray`.
`@"abc"` is the `NSString`, which is an object.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a typo in my code here on SO. My code has the @... and is not sorting.

Comment: You *can't* sort `mySet`, or any other set. He says in a comment on TechZen's answer that he did, in fact, log the set instead of the sorted array.